# Sequence of functions converging into a non differentiable function.

Tags: real-analysis

Okay I want to find a sequence of differentiable functions that converge into a continuous, somewhere non differentiable function. My original idea was to start with $x^2$ and "smooth" it out till it was $|x|$. I am confused as to how to do this specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $f_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}}$, $n \in \mathbb{N},\ x \in \mathbb{R}$? $f_n(x) \rightarrow \lvert x \rvert$ pointwise.

The idea came from asymptotes of a hyperbola.

Comment: Well...In fact domain can be any subset of $\mathbb R$ containing the point $0$.